# How to delete [NaN] from a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have the following

```
a = [[u'63764'], [u'63764'], [u'63764'], [u'70272'], [u'98362'], [u'NaN'], [u'NaN']]
```

How do I delete all those `[NaN]`s to get:

```
a = [[u'63764'], [u'63764'], [u'63764'], [u'70272'], [u'98362']]
```

Thank You

Comment: Why do you have a list of 1-element lists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`math.isnan`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.isnan) to check whether the number is `NaN`:

```
>>> NaN = float('nan')
>>> import math
>>> math.isnan(1)
False
>>> math.isnan(NaN)
True
```

with [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> [xs for xs in a if not any(math.isnan(x) for x in xs)]
[[1], [1], [2], [2], [2], [3], [3]]
```

**UPDATE** according to the question edit:

```
>>> a = [[u'63764'], [u'63764'], [u'63764'], [u'70272'], [u'98362'], [u'NaN'], [u'NaN']]
>>> [x for x in a if x != [u'NaN']]
[[u'63764'], [u'63764'], [u'63764'], [u'70272'], [u'98362']]
```

Comment: It is giving me this error - TypeError: a float is required
I have updated the question. Can you pls take a look at it again?

Comment: @user3309069, I updated the answer according to the question edit.