# How to remove nan's from list of lists?

Tags: python

I am trying to remove all the nans from a list of lists and my data is as follows:

```
[[1,2,3,nan,nan,nan],[4,5,nan],[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan]]
```

I've tried doing this from this answer here ([How to delete [NaN] from a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21773068/10757177)):

```
import math
l = [[1,2,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],[4,5,np.nan],[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]]
[xs for xs in l if not any(math.isnan(x) for x in xs)]
```

But it removes the entire list rather than just the nan's

Comment: The issue with that answer is that it deletes the list but not the nans in the list. In fact, that's the same thing I've done before

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try iterating over the list and building a new list using numpy's [isnan](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) method.

```
import numpy as np
nan = np.nan
l = [[1,2,3,nan,nan,nan],[4,5,nan],[9,8,7,6,5,4,3, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]]
[[x for x in y if not np.isnan(x)] for y in l]
```

Comment: You may also use math.isnan instead, if your env has no numpy installed.

Answer (score 1):

Without `numpy`, using `math` module:

```
import math
nan = float('nan')
l = [[1,2,3,nan,nan,nan],[4,5,nan],[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan]]
l = [[j for j in i if not math.isnan(j)] for i in l]

print(l)
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]]
```