# How to remove NaN from list of lists with string entries?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to remove all the nans from a list of lists (with string entries) and my data is as follows:

```
[['beer', 'nuts', nan], 
['beer', 'butter', 'apple'], 
['beer', 'nuts', 'cheese'], 
['beer', 'bananas', nan], 
['beer', 'nuts', 'apple']]
```

I would like to get this result:

```
[['beer', 'nuts'], 
['beer', 'butter', 'apple'], 
['beer', 'nuts', 'cheese'], 
['beer', 'bananas'], 
['beer', 'nuts', 'apple']]
```

I've tried doing the answers from ([How to remove nan's from list of lists? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56656513/how-to-remove-nans-from-list-of-lists)
 and [How to delete [NaN] from a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21773068/how-to-delete-nan-from-a-list-of-lists)) namely:

```
import math
nan = float('nan')

store_data_list = [[x for x in y if not math.isnan(x)] for y in store_data_list] #remove nans from list of lists

#AND

store_data_list = [xs for xs in store_data_list if not any(math.isnan(x) for x in xs)]

#AND

store_data_list = [[x for x in y if not np.isnan(x)] for y in store_data_list]
```

Both seem not to work in my instance. I get the errors:

> TypeError: must be real number, not str
>
> TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Can someone please indicate what I am doing wrong

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the **complete** Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to compare the item with itself (which is false for nan)

```
nan = float('nan')
data = [['beer', 'nuts', nan], 
        ['beer', 'butter', 'apple'], 
        ['beer', 'nuts', 'cheese'], 
        ['beer', 'bananas', nan], 
        ['beer', 'nuts', 'apple']]
[[i for i in j if i == i] for j in data]
```

gives

```
[['beer', 'nuts'],
 ['beer', 'butter', 'apple'],
 ['beer', 'nuts', 'cheese'],
 ['beer', 'bananas'],
 ['beer', 'nuts', 'apple']]
```

Answer (score 2):

`math.isnan` takes a `float` as argument, not a `str`, you could do this check before using `math.isnan`:

```
store_data_list = [[x for x in y if type(x) != float or not math.isnan(x)] for y in store_data_list]

print(store_data_list)
```

Output:

```
[['beer', 'nuts'],
 ['beer', 'butter', 'apple'],
 ['beer', 'nuts', 'cheese'],
 ['beer', 'bananas'],
 ['beer', 'nuts', 'apple']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
my_list = pd.Series(['a','b', np.NaN, 'c'])
my_new_list = ["Sample_text" if pd.isnull(element) else element for element in my_list]
my_new_list
```

OutPut :

```
['a', 'b', 'Sample_text', 'c']
```